# WCF + Azure = Nightmare!

Tags: azure

I've spent the prior week trying to get a secure form of WCF to work on Azure, but all to no avail!  My use case is pretty simple.  I want to call a WCF endpoint in the cloud and pass messages to be queued for a Worker Role.  Beyond that I want to limit access to pre-authrorized users, authenticated via username & password.

I've tried to get this working with Transport, TransportWithMessageCredential and Message security but nothing seems to work.  Indeed, I've worked through every example and snippet that I could find, most recently the "Service using binary HTTP binding with transport security and message credentials and Silverlight client" example on the http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure page.  I'm pretty sure that I'm being knocked down by small bugs and beta changes but the end result is that I'm totally stuck.

This is a critical path item for me so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  A complete working example or a walkthrough would be even better!

Comment: If you could add details about specific problems you're encountering, it would be helpful for anyone answering you.  Right now, this isn't much of a question, per se.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details!  Basically, I want to have a secure service that WinGUI apps can call to post trades and other related "tasks" to an Azure queue.  All of the tasks would be stateless and idempotent.  Dozens of users will each need to pass credentials to the service in order to be authenticated and authorized.  As to security mode I would prefer Message security but would be fine with TranportWithMessageCredential security also.  Beyond those I am open to using the .NET Service Bus but have yet to get an example to work right for me.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for authentication of WCF calls with only a username and password?

Comment: First of all this is not gimmecodez website, so you should show that you've done so far. The best way of doing this is presenting your code. Further, according to the title you seem to blame the technologies rather than looking for the solution of your problem.

Comment: My advice is to look at faq before posting a question.

Answer (score 4):

Can't answer your question per se - but have you checked out:

- [Windows Azure + WCF samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure)
- [Hosting WCF services in Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/04/07/hosting-wcf-services-in-windows-azure.aspx)
- [Building distributed applications with .NET Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569759.aspx)
- [Windows Azure Whitepapers by Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/01/16/microsoft-net-services-whitepapers-by-pluralsight.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a lot of issues protecting my web service via user name and password as well. I finally choose Message security via Certificate it seemed to be easier to implement.
[Step by step message security WCF](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms)

Comment: Aaron, did you deploy this on the Azure cloud? Or is this a plain vanila WCF security endpoint with certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to do this with anonymous users, but perhaps my setup will get you help you to figure it out. The code below I know work with anonymous users, perhaps you can fiddle with it to get it working with authentication. Also, the only way to secure a Web endpoint is to expose it through HTTPS, using transport security ( source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx ).

**web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Inferface**

IExample.cs:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WebPages.Interfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IExample
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetSomething(string id);
    }
}
```

**ExampleService.svc.cs markup**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebPages.Interfaces.ExampleService" CodeBehind="ExampleService.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

**ExampleService.svc.cs codebehind**

```
namespace WebPages.Interfaces
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ExampleService : IExample
    {
        string JsonSerializeSomething(Something something)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(something.GetType());
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, something);

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        public string GetSomething(string id)
        {
            var something = DoSomeBusinessLogic(id);

            return JsonSerializeSomething(something);
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery call from client**

```
function _callServiceInterface(id, delegate) {
    var restApiCall = "Interfaces/ExampleService.svc/GetSomething?id="
            + escape(id);

    $.getJSON(restApiCall, delegate);
}

function _getSomethingFromService() {
    _callServiceInterface('123',
        function (result) {
            var parsedResult = $.parseJSON(result);
            $('#info').html(result.SomethingReturnedFromServiceCall);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question and Im not entirely sure where your solution failed but from what I understand you need a digital certificate from a recognised trusted source, not just a privately created certificate to make WCF work with Azure.

If you dont use one then as I understand it the WCF will fail but not really say why. So you can end up chasing the ghost of a code bug that's not actually there.